# Impresion de variables antes de bucle

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a1 = "aa";
        String a2 = "bb";
        String a3 = "cc";
        String a4 = "dd";

        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            String a5 = ("a"+ i);
            System.out.println("a"+i +"= "+a5);
        }
}
```

Quisiera saber como se puede de alguna manera imprimir el valor de las variables de arriba en el `for` de esa manera o no se puede porque ahi imprime a1 ,a2 y asi y lo que quiero es que imprima el valor de `a1` o sea `aa`.

Gracias x la ayuda de antemano

Answer (score -7, accepted):

Hola tu problema es que estas reemplazando la variable a1, a2

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a1 = "aa";
    String a2 = "bb";
    String a3 = "cc";
    String a4 = "dd";

    String[] dato = {a1, a2, a3, a4};

    for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){

        String a5 = ("a"+ i); // esto no deberias hacer
        System.out.println("a"+i +"= "+dato[i]);
    }
```

}

Comment: Parece no haber una diferencia con el codigo de ejemplo del OP.

Comment: estoy comentando la línea que no debería colocar, si hay diferencia.

Comment: ¿En serio, esta es la respuesta aceptada? O_O

Comment: Wow! trato de entender como a través de tu código pueda imprimir el valor `aa`. Revisar: http://rextester.com/live/GJZI51438

Answer (score 3):

Lo que tratas de realizar es evaluar `"a"+ i` , como si fuera una variable por ejemplo `a1`, `a2`, etc. Esto no es posible:

```
 String a5 = ("a"+ i);
```

Si deseas obtener imprimir los datos, una opción es crear un array que contenga elementos tipo `String` y agregar estos valores.

```
  /* String a1 = "aa";
   String a2 = "bb";
   String a3 = "cc";
   String a4 = "dd";*/

    String[] elementos = {"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
```

Recuerda que puedes acceder los elementos de una array mediante su indice. Por ejemplo:

- `elementos[0]` tendrá el valor `"aa"`.
- `elementos[1]` tendrá el valor `"bb"`.
- `elementos[2]` tendrá el valor `"cc"`.
- `elementos[3]` tendrá el valor `"dd"`.

Para imprimirlos lo realizarías de esta forma, accediendo a los valores dentro del array:

```
for(int i = 0; i<elementos.length; i++){            
        System.out.println("a"+i +"= "+elementos[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En un lenguaje de programación como Java, lo que tratas de hacer **no es posible, y no tiene sentido tampoco**.

El motivo es que los nombres de variables solo tienen sentido en tiempo de compilación, no están disponibles en tiempo de ejecución, ni si quiera mediante reflection.

En la línea `String a5 = ("a"+ i);` donde armas el nombre de la variable, es un simple string que al final será impreso como tal, en esta línea: `System.out.println("a"+i +"= "+a5);` por lo que obtienes `"a1"`, `"a2"`, `"a3"` y `"a4"`.

Para cuando esas líneas se están ejecutando, el compilador de java ya hace rato habrá convertido el código fuente en bytecode que no conservan los nombres de variables y tales variables como tal se referencian mediante posiciones en la pila o registros de cpu.

Comment: Encontre un ejemplo usando reflexion en Java, podria ser valido algo asi?

Comment: Me refería a que no tiene sentido en Java, desde el punto de vista sintáctico en el lenguaje. En otros lenguajes como JavaScript si es posible y si tiene sentido

Comment: La especificación actual no lo permite, lo sin sentido está en que no se mentiene en tiempo de ejecución el nombre de las variables. Si en alguna especificación futura se almacenara el nombre de las variables junto con la metadata de las clases, entonces si podría tener sentido intentar obtenerla por reflection

Answer (score 2):

### Codigo

```
package Interfaz;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Clase {

    public String a1 = "aa";
    public String a2 = "bb";
    public String a3 = "cc";
    public String a4 = "dd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassLoader cargador = Clase.class.getClassLoader();
        Class clase;
        Object objeto;

        try {

            clase = cargador.loadClass("Interfaz.Clase");
            objeto = clase.newInstance();

            Field[] campos = clase.getFields();

            for (Field campo : campos) {
                Object valor = campo.get(objeto);
                System.out.println(valor);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Clase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

---

### Resultado

```
run:
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

---

### Explicacion

La mayoria de los lenguajes de programacion cuentan con un concepto conocido como la **Reflexion**, esta consiste en poder acceder a ciertos elementos, funciones, metodos, Etc. Usando referencias a estos a traves de sus nombres.

#### Que quiere decir esto?

Esto nos sugiere que hay lenguajes en los que facilmente podrias hacer algo como :

```
funcion(){
   return 1;
}

llamarFuncion("funcion");
```

Casos como estos existen en PHP, C++, Java, Etc.

---

### Vamos al grano

Usando el metodo `getFields` de Java, podemos acceder a **todas las variables cuya visibilidad sea publica**, por lo tanto hacemos uso de dicha funcion sobre la clase `Clase` obteniendo de ella todas las variables declaradas, para este caso `a1,a2,a3,a4` y alli pudiendo obtener posteriormente sus valores.

Comment: Ivan, a1, a2, a3 y a4 en tu código ya no son variables sino miembros de la clase

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Tienes razon, pero quiza al OP le pueda servir para el requerimiento que tenga

Comment: En ese caso es mucho más simple hacer lo que menciona @Jorgesys

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Efectivamente, previ una solucion como esa en un principio, pero supuse que usando reflexion podria solucionarse.  Igual no pasa nada, entre mas soluciones mejor :)

Answer (score 0):

### Sí se puede hacer desde un punto de vista conceptual.

Tu quieres poder asociar valores ("aa", "bb" ..) a unas "variables" a las que das unos nombres ("a1", "a2" ...). Y quieres poder acceder a esas "variables" construyendo su nombre dinámicamente.

Pongo variables entre comillas porque en el caso estricto de variables dentro de un método, que son las que aparecen en tu ejemplo, no es posible, que yo sepa, ni siquiera con reflexión. Pero sí es posible tener un mecanismo que te permita asociar unos valores a unos nombres. Ese mecanismo se llama **MAPA**.

Un mapa es un contenedor asociativo. Viene a ser como un arreglo (array). Pero en un arreglo el índice de acceso solo puede ser un entero, en un mapa puede ser cualquier tipo de dato, y en los mapas se le suele llamar **clave** en vez de índice.

Con el siguiente código creamos un mapa que asocia valores de tipo TipoValor a claves de tipo TipoClave.

```
Map<TipoClave, TipoValor> var = new HashMap<>();
```

En nuestro caso utilizaremos String como TipoClave y String como TipoValor.

Para asignar (o usando la terminología de los mapas **asociar**) un valor a una clave usamos put. Las cuatro primeras líneas del main del autor original quedarían así :

```
Map<String, String> variables = new HashMap<>();
variables.put("a1", "aa");
variables.put("a2", "bb");
variables.put("a3", "cc");
variables.put("a4", "dd");
```

Para leer el valor asociado a una clave utilizamos el método get. El código del autor original usando mapas sería:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=4; i++){
    String a5 = ("a"+ i);
    System.out.println("a"+i +"= "+ variables.get(a5) );
}
```